# Cannot find config option "CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP" for kdump

Tags: kernel, configuration

I'm studying on [kdump](http://lse.sourceforge.net/kdump/) which is a linux kernel crash dumping mechansim. According to `documentation/kdump/kdump.txt` under the kernel source tree, I need to set the kernel config option `CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y`.

> Dump-capture kernel config options (Arch Independent)
>   1) Enable "kernel crash dumps" support under "Processor type and features":
>   CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y

But after `make menuconfig`, I cannot find "kernel crash dumps" as said, and cannot find `CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP` by searching file `.config`, why?

More info may be helpful:
- I'm using SLES11.
- Arch is X86_64
- The .config file is initially from /proc/config.gz.
- Find a option looks similar: `CONFIG_CRASHER=m`

Answer (score 5):

It's called 'kernel crash dumps', under the 'Processor type and features' menu.

A helpful hint: you can use '/' to search for CONFIG_ symbols in the menuconfig tool. It'll tell you where to find it.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that kdump is not supported by Xen kernels prior to Service Pack 2, see "aditional information" in this post http://www.novell.com/support/viewContent.do?externalId=3374462&sliceId=1